# PhoneGap status bar notification

Tags: blackberry, cordova

Does anyone know how to implement a status bar notification for blackberry PhoneGap apps? I mean like when someone receives a notification it should appear as a small image icon on the home screen at the top of the blackberry just as email alerts appear.

Answer (score 0):

To just show an icon with a number you can use the showBannerIndicator which is part of webworks.

e.g.

```
function notify()
{
    blackberry.app.showBannerIndicator('notifyicon.png', 1);
}
```

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.app.html#.showBannerIndicator

If you want to make it clickable you will need to look at trying to implement the community addon from here which will be a bit more work:

https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Community-APIs/tree/master/Smartphone/MessageList

I've successfully used the bannerindicator in a phonegap application, but I havn't tried the MessageList yet.